# How to query workspace-attached Azure Application Insights using .NET?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

I'm looking for a way to query the logs of a LogAnalytics Workspace-attached Application Insights.

[This article](https://taurit.pl/query-application-insights-with-csharp/) described the old way, with the deprecated SDK. I know that I could in theory query the underlying LAW but then every table name is pre-pended with "app", plus the table structures in general seem to differ. E.g. I would need to rewrite the following (most simple) query like:

```
Requests
| take 10

==>

AppRequests
| take 10
```

Obviously I would like to avoid needing to do that, hence I'm looking if there is a native way using the new Azure.Monitor.Query nuget package?

Comment: See if following helps : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/get-started-queries?force_isolation=true

Comment: Are you looking for strong typed query capabilities? If so, that does not exists. All SDKs are based upon writing kusto queries.

Comment: No, I know it’s all kql, that’s what I’m looking for

Comment: Then I probably don't understand the question correctly. Using the Azure.Monitor.Query is a good approach. But yes, in workspace based app insights resources you have different table names. Not much to do about that.

Comment: @PeterBons it's not just the table names, the table structure also is different. Hence, I'm looking if there is a way to reuse existing AppInsights queries without rewriting them from scratch

Comment: I am afraid there is no work around for this.